# Static Text in Permalink

Tags: permalinks

Can i have a static text in Permalink like this => /%post_id%/sometext/%postname%/

I tested this and works fine, but i am concerned whether it will bring some issues in future. So looking for some thoughts from people who have more experience in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem. Every `/` is already a static string. Avoid non-ASCII characters, dots (`.`) and `%`, restrict the string to lowercase letters a—z and *maybe* numbers – but make sure the pagination rules do not conflict with it. A static string `/2/` might be read as page 2 by WordPress.

Besides that, you can use whatever you want.

Comment: Hi toscho, thanks a lot for the detailed reply. Just didn't get this part : test pagination, will this kind of permalink affect the pagination?

Comment: @newbie I made an edit to my answer to explain that better.

Comment: Thanks for the update, couldn't up vote your answer, thanks again for your response, good day.